# Is it possible to have params[:customer] created in index action (rails 3.2.12)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

In our customer model (rails 3.2.12), a method `find_customers` is defined as follows:

```
def find_customers
      customers = Customerx::Customer.scoped  
      customers = customers.where("sales_id = ?", sales_id_s) if sales_id_s.present?
      customers
end
```

The `sales_id_s` is passed in via `params[:customer][:sales_id_s]` through a view form. We want to use the same `find_customers` method to return customers in customers controller index action. The code is:

```
def index

      if has_index_individual_right?('customerx_customers')
        params[:customer][:sales_id_s] = session[:user_id]
        customer = Customerx::Customer.new(params[:customer])
        @customers = customer.find_customers
      else
        ......
      end
      ......
end
```

However the code `params[:customer][:sales_id_s] = session[:user_id]` causes the error: `undefined method`[]=' for nil:NilClass`. In debug, params[:customer] returns nil.

Is there a way to create `params[:customer]` object in index action so we can call the model method `find_customers`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ensure it exists (and is a Hash) by using this `params[:customer] ||= {}`